# Mongoose suddenly broken, not getting callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is the strangest, most frustrating issue I've yet to encounter with Node.js and Mongoose. I don't know what has cause this to be happening at all, but none of my Model functions are executing. For example, I have a model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email : {...},
    password: {...},
    etc...

module.exports = UserSchema
```

All schemas are in their own file, and then made into models in the models/index.js:

```
const UserSchema = require('./UserModel')
const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
module.exports.User = User
```

There are routes to `/login` and `/register`, and these routes have worked fine before, but now it seems the actual mongoose calls, like `findOne`, are never actually being called, and it's thoroughly stumping me.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
// This is inside an AuthController, which is called by the Express router
console.log('a')
UserModel.findOne({'email':email}, (error, result) => {
    console.log('b')
    if (error) callback(error)
    else callback(null,result)
})
```

Now, I always see 'a' in the console, but I am never given an error or the result. For example, 'b' would never be printed to the console.

Is there something simple I am missing? Why did it break seemingly out of nowhere? Why aren't these functions being called?

Comment: Anything changed since it worked? Also, how are you importing the model into the controller?

Comment: Model imported to controller from the `models/index.js` file I mentioned in the OP. `const UserModel = require('../models').User`

Comment: I'd suggest to start with db connection problems. This is the only reason that comes to mind.

Comment: Shouldn't that at least cause an error and trigger one of my callbacks? I've been using Mlab for testing, afaik they haven't gone down. This is just such a weird issue for me

Comment: So @estus, your comment had me curious, so I console.logged mongoose.connection.readyState. Turns out when the mongoose-seeder module I wrote closes it's connection, it closes the original connection as well. Still surprised that doesn't result in an error though.

Comment: I don't remember what happens exactly under the hood but it chains connection promise in queries. In case a connection is closed, it could await for new connection or something like that. You could open an issue on GH regarding this situation.